# Tool to make a master solution from lots of smaller solutions? (vs2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I've been looking for a while for a tool that will take a bunch of solutions and combine them into one large solution, while preserving dependencies between projects.  Does such a tool exist for Visual Studio 2010?

The situation is I have a bunch of separate solution files for a very large product.  I would like operations like "Find All References" to work but it doesn't search across solutions.  I would like to create a "master solution" with all the projects, in addition to all the smaller solutions.  I don't want to create it manually because there are many solutions and even more projects.

Thanks,
-Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the configurations Microsoft Visual Studio has, I think it's not possible. Because in each solution you might have one or more startup projects, a specialized Configuration Manager, Solution Folders and many other settings that depends on your solution file.

One of the policies I always use is to not have many many projects to lost between them. I strongly recommend you to combine your projects, see what's happening and group them into a few large projects, instead of having many little projects. Also I'd suggest you to use TFS, it's a great server for team management and such a things you're looking for.

Cheers

Comment: Ahh, well that's too bad.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. Since you have exactly the same build platforms and configurations then you could try http://slntools.codeplex.com/. It's not exactly what you need but according it's documentation you can have one big master solution and create subsolutions of it automatically...

Comment: Hmm interesting I will give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: It will work if you have a master solution which contains all projects and dependencies defined. Then you can create temporary working solutions from there.